# 301 Redirect all 404 pages in a directory that don't follow a current rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !product_id=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/index.php [R=301]
```

This 301 redirects product URLs to my root directory based on product ID.  (I didn't make it I got it from someone else)

What I need to do is keep this rule in place whilst redirecting any 404 pages in the same directory to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding these rules *before* the rule that you already have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

This assumes the homepage you are talking about is the document root. So for example, if `/blah` doesn't exist and would normally result in a 404, going to `http://yourdomain.com/blah` would redirect to `http://yourdomain.com/`.

Comment: hmm it appears that SH404SEF and Joomla are intercepting the 404 pages...  the first code works to redirect any products but anything else gets intercepted :(

Comment: @user1951915 If you're using something like Joomla and everything is being routed to a controller, you need to do this through Joomla, and not htaccess

Comment: @user1951915 You mean the rules you have in your question? That rule's condition is whether there doesn't exist a query string `product_id`, regardless of whether a file exists or not.